# disable and enable chips list

Tags: angular-material

I need to get a list in which once a name is selected in that list it must display in a chip/chips format in angular (typescript) and the name which we have selected must be disabled in the list. If the selected name is deleted that particular name must display in the current chip/chips list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there are basically two approaches to achieve what you want.

1. You can create another array for selected items, then after selecting name from the list you can push the item to `selectedItems` array. `selectedItems` array could be then used to display chips. Also if an item on the main list is in `selectedItems` array then it should be disabled.
2. You can create field in an item called `isSelected` which will be the type of boolean. For example:

```
item{
  name: string;
  isSelected = false;
}
```

then if an item has flag `isSelected` set on true it should be displayed in chip and disabled in list. Clicking on an item in the main list should only change the `isSelected` value to true.